# Windows 10 UAC asks for email and password instead of local admin credentials

Tags: windows-10, uac

I just reinstalled Windows 10 Education provided by my university. I am running as a regular user, but am trying to install a program.

However, UAC is asking for an email address and password, whereas the actual admin account is local. How do I get Windows to accept the local admin credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a local account, you need to add ".\" in front of the user. That will set the "domain" to the local system. Example:

```
Username: .\LocalAdmin
Password: Password
```

Comment: Okay, I am glad to know that this is normal.